# Buffalo WZR 1750dhp - Can't reach the LAN side using wireless

Tags: router

I have a desktop LINUX box (Ubuntu 14.04 Server) wired to my new WZR 1750dhp router and can connect to the internet from it.  I can connect to the internet from my notebook through the router using WiFi but desktop which is what I must be able to do.  I can connect to the desktop if the notebook is connected to the router via a LAN cable. I have forwarded 4 desktop ports.

Any idea what settings control this and how to fix it?
I'm just a LINUX user, not an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://manual.buffalo.jp/buf-doc/35013154-04_EN.pdf) that router supports SSID and Wireless Client isolation, my guess is you have Wireless Client Isolation (or both?) turned on, so the WiFi client are isolated form the wired network.

> If enabled, the Wireless Client Isolation blocks communication between wireless devices connected to the AirStation. Wireless devices will be able to connect to the Internet but not with each other. Devices that are connected to the AirStation with wired connections will still be able to connect to wireless devices normally.

SSID isolation would prevent communication between multiple Wifi network/SSID's (if you have multiple configured).

> Enable to make wireless devices connected to the specified SSID be able to communicate only with the Internet-side.

Check in the Web UI under Advanced Settings -> "Wireless - 2.4 GHz" and "Wireless - 5 GHz" for these settings.

Comment: Just as the last sentence says in the original answer, "Devices that are connected to the AirStation with wired connections will still be able to connect to wireless devices normally".. Wireless Client Isolation is just for wireless devices and blocks wireless to wireless communication, it should not be blocking wireless to wired or vise-versa communications

Answer (score 1):

Check for "guest isolation" in router wifi properties and disable it.
Some wireless routers have a function called "guest isolation". With this option enabled, wifi connected hosts can't wiew other connected hosts on the network. Disabling this feature should solve the issue.